# using guard to check for nil without implicitly unwrapping

Tags: swift

I know there are some similar questions around, but I couldn't find one specific to my issue. 
I have a request where I want to check for the presence of the `error` key. it is not present everything is fine, if not I should handle the error. Currently, I have it implemented as follows:

```
if let error = json["error"] {
    // handle error
}
else {
    // handle success
}
```

I would like to use a guard statement here to have the success case unindented. The only way I came up with is

```
guard json["error"] == nil else {
    let error = json["error"]!
    // handle error
} 

// handle success
```

but that seems wrong to me with the !. Are there any other approaches to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `guard` code you would have to have a return statement in the else block. Like this...

```
guard json["error"] == nil else {
    let error = json["error"]!
    // handle error
    return
}

// handle success
```

But you are correct. Having to force unwrap the error is not ideal.

So in this case. I think `guard` is the wrong solution. Instead use `if` but return from the conditional block. This removes the need for using an else block.

```
if let error = json["error"] {
    print(error)
    // handle error
    return
}

// handle success...
// no need for else block. Just return from the if in the error case.
```

The difference between `guard let` and `if let` is where the unwrapped optional is scoped.

With guard it is scoped outside the block with if it is scoped inside the block.

Comment: Ok i see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: I downvoted as it doesn't really answer the question, which is how to how to bring the `let` scope *into* the `guard` block, rather than the scope *below* the `guard` block. Using a `guard` (rather than `if let` as you propose) is key, as it enforces the required `return`. I don't think the solution to the current awkward negative `guard` is to *not use a guard statement*.

Comment: @pkamb well the answer to that is “you can’t”. That would be a stupid answer as it doesn’t help at all.

Comment: I disagree that that would be a stupid answer, and it *does* help to know that that construct is not currently supported. Good to mention `if let` as a potential alternative, but it should be weighed against just using the slightly awkward `guard`.

Comment: @pkamb your logic is beyond understanding. Feel free to downvote. It makes absolutely no sense to me. What you are suggesting as an answer offers less to the poster than what I actually answered. Sometimes people ask questions that require more than a straight answer. I have learned this over several years of using Stack Overflow. Anyway, it’s up to you how you vote answers or questions.

Answer (score 3):

An idea for your issue was proposed on the Swift Evolution mailing list:

> ### "guard not let" optional binding
>
> https://forums.swift.org/t/idea-guard-not-let-optional-binding/2614
>
> [it is] fairly common that you want to check that an optional *is* nil, and still bail if it isn’t (maybe using the value that you now know exists), e.g:
>
> `guard cachedValue == nil else { return cachedValue! }`
> `cachedValue = //… expensive calculation`
>
> It seems a little bit “unfair” that we have this lovely clean `let` syntax when checking for Optional.Some, but we to have to do this ugly manual check against nil and explicit unwrap when checking for Optional.None. There is literally no other way to satisfy the guard statement; our optional bindings only go one-way can’t be evaluated.

Unfortunately that construct does not currently exist in Swift.

The alternatives are the slightly awkward/duplicated `guard` syntax, possibly with a force-unwrap:

```
guard json["error"] == nil else {
    return json["error"]!
}
```

or using `if-let` (which does **not** enforce scope-exit like `guard`):

```
if let error = json["error"] {
    return error
}
```